# Multiline echo without /r /n and /t in encoded JSON (PHP)

Tags: php, ajax, xmlhttprequest, heredoc, ob-start

When creating a response for XHR-requests with PHP using ob_get_clean() and json_encode, the response contains unnecessary new lines (**/r**, **/n**) and tabs (**/t**). They serve no visible purpose for the user, but consume bandwidth anyways.

Removing them with `str_replace` solves the problem, while causing another: It also removes necessary linebreaks within textareas.

```
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");

ob_start();

echo "
test
<textarea>
</textarea>
test
";

$test = json_encode(ob_get_clean());

echo $test;
```

Output:

```
\r\ntest\r\n<textarea>\/r\/n<\/textarea>\r\ntest\r\n
```

---

Removing them with str_replace:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");

ob_start();

echo "
test
<textarea>
</textarea>
test
";

$test = ob_get_clean();
$test = str_replace(PHP_EOL, NULL, $test);
$test = json_encode($test);

echo $test;
```

Output:

```
test<textarea><\/textarea>test
```

---

However:

How to get rid of **/r** **/n** and **/t** without messing up textareas?

More openly asked:

Is there another (or better) solution for attaching multiple lines of html-elements to a variable other than `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean()`?

Comment: Why do you call json_encode?

Comment: @akrys json_encode is inevitable in my case. I'm not just loading a html-file.

Comment: The newlines are there because you put them there in your string. Why not just remove them? https://3v4l.org/qQrud

Comment: @Nick Because we're talking about a huge amount of html elements (basically a whole webpage) which is being loaded, including if/else-conditions and other php-tasks like for/foreach. You can't avoid using linebreaks there.

Comment: So the actual use case is not a simple `echo`?

Comment: @Nick Whatever code is generated needs to be assigned to a variable and then json_encoded. One possibility would be to attach the data line by line (using $var .= $text). But considering the amount of data i'm working with, tentousends of lines, that's not a real option. ob_start() and ob_get_clean() solves that problem but also creates /r, /n and /t as displayed in the source code.